# problem completing renderResponse phase after redirecting to a servlet from a JSF page in portal environment

Tags: file, jsf, download, portlet

1. I have a commandLink in a JSF page in a portal environment. On clicking it, I redirect to a servlet (by calling facesContext.getExternalcontext().sendRedirect(//Servlet URL//)).
2. the servlet is created for downloading an excel file from the server.
3. A Save As File dialog opens up with the JSF Portal page in the background.

This works fine, but when I have downloaded the file, I find that when I click on any action component on the portal JSF page, it just refreshes the page instead of performing the action. I have to click that action component again for it to work.

When I used a PhaseListener to track the JSF lifecycle, I find that after the redirect, Step 6, i.e.renderResponse phase is missing. Could this be the issue? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug in the Javascript generated by the JSF component in question. What make/version is it? Sun JSF RI 1.1? I recall some bugs like this, but those are already fixed more than 3 years ago. Make sure that you're using the latest version of the JSF implementation in question. You can get Sun Mojarra (formerly known as Sun JSF RI) [here](http://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net) and Apache MyFaces [here](http://myfaces.apache.org).